# Mac Mini stops accepting ssh connections from different network

Tags: networking, ssh, mac-osx, mac

I have a strange problem, and I am not very familiar with Mac OSX so I am coming here for help.

I have two Mac Minis on a network 192.168.1.*

Mac Mini 1 = 192.168.1.10
Mac Mini 2 = 192.168.1.11

My workstation is on 10.1.10.*
VPN on 192.168.2.*

About once every two days or so the Mac Mini 2 stops accepting ssh connections from any network other than it's own. I cannot ping it or anything from my workstation, but if I ssh into Mac Mini 1 and then ssh to Mac mini 2 from there it works and magically I can then ping and ssh from my workstation.

the sshd-config is the same on the two minis. I thought the machines were identical, but I just discovered that Mac Mini 1 is running OSX 10.7.4 and Mini 2 is running OSX 10.7.2. Could that be a clue?

Any ideas?

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond!

Comment: Is Mac Mini 1 going to sleep? Apple plays some tricks with Bonjour sleep proxies to wake sleeping computers when they're accessed over the network, but that might not work over the VPN connection (but would work from another Mac on the same network, and then once it was awake it'd work over VPN as well).

Comment: Need more info. (1) Netmask of 192.168.1.0/?? and 192.168.2.0/?? (2) How is vpn setup? (OS X VPN service? VPN connection is NAT/Bridge/Route to LAN?)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I figured out how to enable vnc from the cmd line, logged in and started rooting around and I found that I missed a power setting (or it got reset). The mini was set to go to sleep (facepalm), but set allow "wake on network"(handy). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above, the darn thing was set to go to sleep, not sure how I could have missed that...